# Translating the passage of a reference to a DLL from VBA to VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, vba, interop, dllimport

I'm trying to rewrite a piece of code that includes C++ dll calls from VBA to VB.NET.
In particular there is a C++ function I'm calling in the dll that performs some actions on a couple of bidimensional arrays of `float` is:

```c++
int __stdcall FindPolarization(int PointsTheta, int PointsPhi, float* Real1, float* Imag1 = nullptr)
{
    double Max[4] = { -999, -999, -999, -999 };         // Max values
    long MaxPos[4][2] = { -999, -999,                   // Max Theta and Max Phi
        -999, -999,
        -999, -999,
        -999, -999 };
    float* Pointers[4][2];
    double DeltaTheta = static_cast<double>(180.0 / PointsTheta);
    double DeltaPhi = static_cast<double>(360.0 / PointsPhi);
    vector<vector<vector<double>>> Ampl;

    // Setup
    Pointers[0][0] = Real1;
    Pointers[0][1] = Imag1;
    Pointers[1][0] = Real2;
    Pointers[1][1] = Imag2;
    Pointers[2][0] = Real3;
    Pointers[2][1] = Imag3;
    Pointers[3][0] = Real4;
    Pointers[3][1] = Imag4;
    if (Real3 != nullptr && Real4 != nullptr && Imag3 != nullptr && Imag4 != nullptr)
    {
        Ampl.resize(4, vector<vector<double>>(PointsTheta + 1, vector<double>(PointsPhi, 0)));
        Real3 = nullptr; Imag3 = nullptr; Real4 = nullptr; Imag4 = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        Ampl.resize(2, vector<vector<double>>(PointsTheta + 1, vector<double>(PointsPhi, 0)));
    }
    Real1 = nullptr; Imag1 = nullptr; Real2 = nullptr; Imag2 = nullptr;

    // Coordinates transformation + Maximum storage
    Concurrency::parallel_for(0, PointsPhi, [&](int j)
    {

        double PhiRad = j * DeltaPhi * Deg2Rad;
        double CosPhi = cos(PhiRad);
        double SinPhi = sin(PhiRad);
        int ind;
        pair<double, double> AmplCoCr;

        for (int i = 0; i <= PointsTheta; i++)
        {

            ind = j * (PointsTheta + 1) + i;

            for (int k = 0; k < static_cast<int>(Ampl.size()); k = k + 2)
            {
                AmplCoCr = AmplCalc(ind, Pointers[k][0], Pointers[k][1], Pointers[k + 1][0], Pointers[k + 1][1], CosPhi, SinPhi);
                Ampl[k][i][j] = AmplCoCr.first;
                Ampl[k + 1][i][j] = AmplCoCr.second;

                if (Ampl[k][i][j] > Max[k])
                {
                    Max[k] = Ampl[k][i][j];
                    MaxPos[k][0] = i;
                    MaxPos[k][1] = j;
                }
                if (Ampl[k + 1][i][j] > Max[k + 1])
                {
                    Max[k + 1] = Ampl[k + 1][i][j];
                    MaxPos[k + 1][0] = i;
                    MaxPos[k + 1][1] = j;
                }
            }
        }

    });

    double A = max(max(Max[0], Max[1]), max(Max[2], Max[3]));
    if (A > Max[1] && A > Max[2] && A > Max[3]) return 45;
    else if (A > Max[0] && A > Max[2] && A > Max[3]) return 135;
    else if (A > Max[0] && A > Max[1] && A > Max[3]) return 90;
    return 0; // else if (A > Max[0] && A > Max[1] && A > Max[2]) 

}


pair<double, double> AmplCalc(int index, float* RealCo, float* ImagCo, float* RealCr, float* ImagCr, double CosPhi, double SinPhi)
{
    double A, B;

    const double RealCoij = static_cast<double>(RealCo[index]);
    const double RealCrij = static_cast<double>(RealCr[index]);
    const double ImagCoij = static_cast<double>(ImagCo[index]);
    const double ImagCrij = static_cast<double>(ImagCr[index]);

    A = RealCoij * CosPhi + RealCrij * SinPhi;
    B = ImagCoij * CosPhi + ImagCrij * SinPhi;
    double Co = 10 * log10(A * A + B * B);

    A = (RealCoij * SinPhi * (-1) + RealCrij * CosPhi);
    B = (ImagCoij * SinPhi * (-1) + ImagCrij * CosPhi);
    double Cr = 10 * log10(A * A + B * B);

    return make_pair(Co, Cr);
}
```

which in the VBA environment is imported with:

```vb
Private Declare Function FindPolarization Lib "EvalFunc.dll" (ByVal PointsTheta As Long, ByVal PointsPhi As Long, ByRef RealLev1 As Single, ByRef ImagLev1 As Single = 0) As Long
```

and called in the code through:

```vb
Dim RealLev1() As Single, ImagLev1() As Single
Dim PolMax As Long, FFThetaPoints As Long, FFPhiPoints As Long

' Arrays are filled here through a function that determines their dimensions and values
FFThetaPoints = UBound(RealLev1, 1)
FFPhiPoints = UBound(RealLev1, 2)
PolMax = FindPolarization(FFThetaPoints, FFPhiPoints, RealLev1(0, 0), ImagLev1(0, 0))
```

This works on VBA, but I've been trying to translate it into VB.NET and failed miserably.

Provided that **I can't change the C++ code inside the dll**, I have stopped at  the following code.
The import of the function looks like:

```vb
 <DllImport("myDll.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _

Public Shared Function FindPolarization(ByVal PointsTheta As Integer, ByVal PointsPhi As Integer, ByRef RealLev1 As Single, _
Optional ByRef ImagLev1 As Single = Nothing) As Integer
End Function
```

And the code calling it would be:

```vb
Dim FFThetaPoints As Integer, FFPhiPoints As Integer, PolMax As Integer
Dim RealLev1(,) As Single = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Single), 1, 1)
Dim ImagLev1(,) As Single = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Single), 1, 1)

FFThetaPoints = UBound(RealLev1, 1)
FFPhiPoints = UBound(RealLev1, 2)
PolMax = ImportDll.FindPolarization(FFThetaPoints, FFPhiPoints, RealLev1(0, 0), ImagLev1(0, 0))
```

Now, those array are `System.Array` type because of a particular function that requires them to be so.

While in VBA I get some result, in VB.NET I obtain other ones. I think this has something to do with how I declare the `Single` arrays, but I am not sure.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need to define a typed array. Try with `Dim RealLev1() As Single = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Single), 1, 1) `

Comment: The VB.NET equivalent of C++'s `int` is `Integer`, not `Long`. Change the first two parameters and the return type of the VB.NET declaration.

Comment: Used the combination of your comments and changed the code accordingly. Now the value of `PolAvg` is always the same, wrong one

Comment: Have you updated your .NET-side logic to account for the change in arrays from column-major in VBA to row-major in .NET?

Comment: @Craig No, I didn't. `FindPolarization` is a function written in C++ that should already take care of that (updated the question, so the code shows), shouldn't it? What I am giving to it are pointers to the 2 dimensional arrays, and what I get back is an `Integer`.

Comment: The issue is that if you directly copied your VBA code into VB.NET, you may need to transpose the arrays.  Nothing changed on the C++ side, rather on the VB side: arrays in VBA are column-major (most-rapidly varying index is the leftmost index) whereas arrays in .NET are row-major (most-rapidly varying index is the rightmost index).  I would imagine that PInvoke can account for this, but I'm not sure of the exact incantations required.  It's something you need to account for in some form or fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to give all the credit to @Craig here.
VBA and VB.NET have indeed different matrix addressing logics (column major vs. row major), so I had to transpose all the 2D arrays, without swapping `FFThetaPoints` and `FFPhiPoints`.

It is worth mentioning that I tried using the `Excel.Application` `Worksheetfunction.Transpose` method, which didn't work as expected. So I had to write my own piece of code to transpose the matrices.